# Function called by window maximise

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, maximize

I was wondering if there is a way of binding a function to a Tkinter window's maximise button. At first I tried the English way of spelling it `root.protocol('WM_MAXIMISE_WINDOW', callback)` (with callback being a simple function). Then I tried spelling it the American way: `root.protocol('WM_MAXIMIZE_WINDOW', callback)`, all with no success. What is the correct way of doing this, if any? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Um I do believe you typed the same thing twice

Comment: Sorry, spell check on my PC is UK, corrected Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a protocol for maximizing the window. I can't find it, at least. You could try something like this, though:

```
def check_maximize(event):
    screen_w, screen_h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    window_w, window_h = root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()

    # check if window is as wide as screen and between height of screen and 100 pixels
    # to compensate for task bar
    if screen_w == window_w and screen_h > window_h > screen_h - 100:
        print('Maximized or Maximised')

root = Tk()

root.bind('<Configure>', check_maximize) # callback on window move/resize

mainloop()
```