# How to handle minimize/maximize buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've researched a lot about this topic, but nothing seems to be helpful. I want to get a callback when I press the minimize/maximize (- button) on my tkinter window. Like when I click on the close button, I can get a callback like this:

```py
# Function for callback
def on_closing():
   print("User clicked close button")
   root.destroy()

# Callback
self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
```

Like this I can callback a function when someone clicks on the close (X) button. So my question is, isn't there a similar protocol for minimize/maximize buttons as well for calling back?

Comment: It looks like a similar question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815494/function-called-by-window-maximise)

Comment: Put this on top.  root.resizable(0,0)

Comment: @Rory yah, I saw that before. But I don't think that's an excellent way to do it in professional coding. Moreover, it doesn't trigger maximizing; it only prints when the window is minimized and cannot tell whether the event is a minimize or maximize.

Comment: @toyotaSupra reread my question. I don't want to make my window non-resizable; I want a callback when that event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to use a `protocol` like with the X button. You can bind to the `'<Map>'` and `'<Unmap>'` events like this.

```
import tkinter as tk


def catch_minimize(event):
    print("window minimzed")


def catch_maximize(event):
    print("window maximized")

    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

root.bind("<Unmap>", catch_minimize)
root.bind("<Map>", catch_maximize)

root.mainloop()
```